# Como fazer funcionar o href que esta dentro da minha div com focus?

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho uma lista que quando clicar em algum item ela recebe um focus e aparece uma div com informações. Uma dessas informações tem um link  mas quando clico nele, minha div fecha e não abre a página.

Segue o código...

HTML completo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            li .faq-content-answer{
                display: none;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            li:focus .faq-content-answer{
                display: block;
            }
            .faq-content-answer p{
                display: none;
            }
            li:focus .faq-content-answer p{
                display: block;
                padding: 18px 0 20px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li tabindex="0">Como me cadastrar?
                <div class="faq-content-answer"><p>Para se cadastrar, <a target="_blank" href="link-clicavel">Clique aqui</a>
                Nós enviaremos um e-mail com as suas informações e se elas estiverem corretas, é só confirmar a aproveitar!</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <body>
</html>
```

Como consigo fazer com que o href funcione quando clicar?

Comment: O que seria "link-clicavel"  dentro do href? não deveria ser o caminho de onde deseja chegar?

Comment: Exato! Coloquei um link avulso para mostrar que não funciona.

Comment: Pode colocar o código completo, dentro do local específico para os códigos ? <> não no {}

Comment: Post editado. o HTML fica assim msm.

Comment: Vê lá @Ikaro Pinheiro vê se te resolve...

Comment: funfou... Avisa ae se naum num consigo dormir...

Comment: hehe, deu certo sim, vlw mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê se é isso patrão:

```css
li{
display:inline:block;
}
.faq-content-answer {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    
}


.faq-content-answer a {
   
    display: block;
}


.faq-content-answer a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}


li:hover .faq-content-answer {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li >Como me cadastrar?
                <div class="faq-content-answer"><p>Para se cadastrar, <a target="_blank" href="link-clicavel">Clique aqui</a>
                Nós enviaremos um e-mail com as suas informações e se elas estiverem corretas, é só confirmar a aproveitar!</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <body>
```

Se gosta se adapta, GL ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como isso? Utilizando a biblioteca jQuery.

```js
$('#div-clicavel').on('click', function() {
  window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
});
```

```html
<div id="div-clicavel">Clique Aqui</div>
```

Comment: A resposta é viável, mas a intenção é não causar esse erro, e a tag agir normalmente sobre a natureza dela.

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer com "causar esse erro" esse código acima não contem erros.